# Symfony2 and ClankBundle: cannot share session

Tags: symfony, session, websocket, ratchet

I am using Symfony2 with ClankBundle for WebSocket funciontality.
I followed the instructions reported [here (PdoSessionHandler)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) and [here (Clank Session sharing)](https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md), but still I am not able to get the information I store inside the session.

I am still using the built-in debug server provided by Symfony that runs on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

My parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    clank_host: 127.0.0.1
    clank_port: 8080
```

My config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo

clank:
    web_socket_server:
        port: "%clank_port%"
        host: "%clank_host%"
    session_handler: session.handler.pdo
```

In the Controller:

```
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('user_token', $user->getId() );
```

In the Topic Service:

```
public function onSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
{
    file_put_contents('debug.txt', "onSubscribe" .$conn->resourceId . " connected" . " ".$conn->Session->get('user_token'). PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    // ...
}
```

And the script in the page:

```
var myClank = Clank.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

myClank.on("socket/connect", function(session){
    console.log("Successfully Connected!");
    session.subscribe("topicservice/channel", function(uri, payload){
        console.log("Received message");
    });
    // ...
})
```

Bit still, when users connect and subscribe, `$conn->Session->get('user_token')` returns null.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was.

Symfony built-in server and clank server both run on `127.0.0.1`, but I was accessing from the browser to `localhost`.

It seems that these are considered two different domains. Good to know.